# dhcp doesn't works after macchanger

Tags: networking, 16.04, dhcp

i am trying to connect to a WLAN using a fake mac.

when i turn on my iface and i try to connect it with its permanent MAC everything goes well:

```
iface=wlan1
essid=my_essid

ifconfig $iface down
service networking restart
ifconfig $iface up
iwconfig $iface essid $essid
dhclient $iface -v -4
```

this script will run without problems.
if i try to use

```
macchanger -e $iface
```

and after run the previous script the dhclient will never end with something good.

can anyone help me?
thanks a lot

Comment: What does dhclient say after you change your mac? never used macchange why not just use `ifconfig wlan1 hw ether 01:02:03:04:05:06`? Can you use network if you set your IP manually/static? Also WiFi could have MAC filtering on

Comment: No, I cant navigate even if I set hw manually. If I open wireshark I find a serie of DHCP Discovery without answer with the ethernet addr changed.

Comment: Sounds like MAC filtering on WiFi

Comment: Another question, all nic are able to spoof mac? How can I check if the mine can do it?

Comment: No, not all, depends on a driver/nic. Run `sudo ifconfig wlan1 hw ether 00:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e` or whichever interface instead of wlan1 if you get an error then it's not supported. If no error confirm that HWaddr changed with `ifconfig -a`

Comment: Evidently it doesn t support it. I am looking around and it seems that broadcom isn t linux friendly and , unfortunately , it is my nic. You deserve a rep but I havent enough privileges to vote a comment. Create an answer with this info rearranged, I will vote up it. Thanks a lot meccooll

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail` a few seconds after you tried unsuccessfully to associate with the access point with a spoofed MAC?

Comment: Hi David ! this question has been solved. The device/driver isn't able to spoof MAC and fails displaying a warning. I was ignoring it but evidently it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all drivers support mac changes. Try to change the mac with

> sudo ifconfig wlan1 hw ether 00:0a:0b:0c:0d:0e

and then confirm that the mac was changed with `ifconfig -a`